# How can I destructure parameters on a function such that it can receive either the entire object or just a part of it?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have a vehicle object as

```
vehicle: {
  make: { //say type Make
    name: "acura",
    model: "rdx"
  },
  user: { //say type User
    name: "abc",
    age: 30
  },
  addr: { //say type Address
    number: 12,
    street: 'xyz ave'
  }
}
```

I want to write a function that can either receive the entire object or a partial object. So I did

```
function display({make}: {make?: Make} = {}, {user}: {user?: User} = {}, {addr}: {addr?: Address} = {}): void {
  if(make) {
    console.log(make.name);
  }
  if(user) {
    console.log(user.name);
  }
  if(addr) {
    console.log(addr.num);
  }
}
display(vehicle); // Should display acura, abc, 12
display(vehicle.user); // Should display abc
```

Now, the above function works if I just pass the make or the entire vehicle object. Except of course it takes it as only the first parameter and the rest are undefined. How do I destructure the params properly to pass either a partial object or the entire object?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgNWAAsFsAbPAbwFgAoOOAW0wGtgAuOAWVeABo6DAK4BnNJwCqYqAPpxMAEwVROAQSVRgIkXQC%20dOqEixEKNFlzdecGnKSZGHOCJhRkAc1kNGEBcDKcLm5I7noGtEbQ8MioGDh4Umg2gnD2joGuHl7y7k5IQowARmhhtIbgUaaxFnjqyloiyXYFnPlFaNlBwMAwGcGhtPpltBTwAG7EpBSchCTkeAC8Td68nJRwKQxpTgBEOEJQmDvZ3r7%20nDtQCiA7KbrZouI2G3JbDruYhdjHmzlOAMwABju2UUyjWLwYWxacAAjAAmE7OVzdXpwADkIAAngAveQTdF3Up0dBCJDYGAICBIOAKBAiMBkTBYgAUlGYbF0aw5wAA-JweJy4EtKPcbI8oFzxdJ%20XBEpLhTYxZQwZK1qrZXVNNpdIrRQBKThjCAIBTLRDoFk8-XmhjYakiCAUAB0ZAg7itvGd231AG4iXIEJaJTbbFC4PakI6XW6PRLve8-QGGEGWarQ79I9HgK73WmNN6Ckm5EMhnQ6QymayJnMKH64AB6BtwADKRAgQjIZorjOZ8mwB0wfHkX2HCPL9N71cm82dId9jebbY7Xdpk6rI%20wQA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m35L1w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use overloads and type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#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-1VAA6Nt-0AsYgONMDgMdDVzy1CUr1bXg73kR9n3pKMqBST9v1VaCIO2AiQLOMg4PCBDvRfScxnvdD+RfU1pA-Ho8N-ADgKIjiIMwXJyOGSjbU3DRUIfJ8GMwxNtBYr8oB-Yi2mIroen4uhpQNVls15YVl3LOAAGUiAgIQyAUO0NPkbADkwPh5C+WyETU31DS0ihIOkHkdMrAyjJMsz1NlOzsCAA)

```
function display(vehicle: Vehicle): void;
function display(make: Make): void;
function display(user: User): void;
function display(addr: Address): void;
function display(target: Vehicle | Make | User | Address): void {
  if (isvehicle(target)) {
    target
    //^?
  }

  if (ismake(target)) {
    target
    //^?
  }

  if (isuser(target)) {
    target
    //^?
  }

  if (isaddr(target)) {
    target
    //^?
  }
}

function isvehicle(v: any): v is Vehicle {
  return v && v.make && v.user && v.addr;
}

function ismake(v: any): v is Make {
  return v && v.name && v.model;
}

function isuser(v: any): v is User {
  return v && v.name && v.age;
}

function isaddr(v: any): v is Address {
  return v && v.num && v.street;
}
```

You can make the type guards as strict/correct if necessary.

- [Type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)
- [Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not just on an external site. Posts on Stack Overflow should be self contained and not require visitors to navigate elsewhere.